# Index of Substring in Original Text

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp, string-matching

I am working on one of Natural Language Processing Problem using **Python**.

My Problem:
Let's consider a string

```
str1 = "United, State is a very nice country"
```

We preprocess this string where we removed all special symbol, URLs, HTML content etc. Now the preprocessed string will become something like this:

```
preprocessed_str = "United State is a very nice country"
```

Then we pass this preprocessed string to my machine learning model which returns results like:

```
Country: United State
```

**Now I want to take start and end index of the "United State" in the original string.**

We tried this with **python's str.find()** function but it returns -1.

I will appreciate the approaches and solution through which we can solve this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `import re; re.search("United.*?state",str1,flags=re.I).span()` should give you a tuple of the start and end

Comment: @Onyambu thanks for the swift reply, but Does this regex will work for 3 words string.

string = "The country is in happy mode said The, United, State president"

print(re.search("The.*?United.*?state", string, flags=re.I).span())

Comment: still use the code I gave. Do not change it. Your aim is United states, so do not add anything to `United.*?State`

Comment: Your biggest problem is that the function that turns your original string into a preprocessed string is not reversible. The preprocessed string `United State is a very nice country` could come from a vast number of different, and (importantly) unpredictably different strings full of special characters and html and urls. You don't even know what the start and end are, let alone what's in the middle. (eg where would be the start/end if the original string was `<b>United, <a href='state'>State</a></b>`?)